# How do I eliminate space between columns so as to make a grid (using images) with no spaces in between them?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a grid of images with no space between them, they will be links and I used the  to make the grid instead of . I've figured out how to get the pictures side-by-side but there is a tiny space between the columns that I cannot get rid of.I am brand new at this all so I don't even know how to post code here without it rendering so I will post a snapshot of what comes up- and code when I figure that out too. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean space between the rows.

It's a bit guesswork without some actual code, but try setting your images to `display:block` - images have `display:inline` by default, causing them to show some line height in some cases.

(Oh and you can post code by adding four spaces in front of each line)

Comment: Thanks ptriek for trying to help--- I substituted the pics for other more 'acceptable' ones and somehow that eliminated the space- then I put back my muse pics and there is no space so I must have done something right.